# How to pass enum values into postman

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman

i have a immutable enum class that i can't change but need to pass value into postman in the same format.

here below is the class.

```
public class Request {

    private int num;
    private Type type;

    public Request(Type type, int num) {
        this.type = type;
        this.num = num;
    }

    public int getNum() {
        return num;
    }

    public Type getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public enum Type {
        MEN, WOMEN , FAMILY, CHILD
    }

}
```

i am looking for exact Json format which is pass through Postman. everytime i am getting 400 error while hitting the endpoint.

Comment: Have you tried passing the enum as a string? Spring handles such cases out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

write a simple program where you can instantiate your `Request` class and serialize it to JSON String. That would be your JSON that you pass as param. But ultimately the API provider is responsible to tell you what input format is expected.
Here is how you can serialize your class to Json String: you can use JSON Jackson library and use [method writeValueAsString Of class ObjectMapper](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.13/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#writeValueAsString-java.lang.Object-). So, just instantiate your `Request` class and pass the instance to this method and you will get your Json String. Also I wrote my own `JsonUtils` utility that my be even simpler but will do the same. use [static method JsonUtils.writeObjectToJsonString](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/JsonUtils.html#writeObjectToJsonString-java.lang.Object-) to serialize your class instance to JSON String. Class JsonUtils comes as part of Open source MgntUtils library. You can get this library as [Maven artifact at Maven central](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) or on [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases).

Comment: @Micheal Gantman some how i need to pass the values from Request class in controller, this request class is responsible to take the values in controller and service layer. can you help on this or any class where i can serialize the Request class to JSON

Comment: @Maveric I updated the answer with details how to do it